# Cauchy integral formula12

Tags: complex-analysis

$\int 1/(z^2 + 2i)dz$

I've tried writting it as $1/(z-1+i)*(z+1-i)$ but then it's impossible to find solution.
Any help would be great, thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered a partial fractions decomposition from here?

Comment: What is the contour over which you are integrating?

Comment: William, i don't know how to do that 
Dr.MV |z|=3

Comment: + is in middle, sorry for mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $I$ be the integral given by

$$I=\oint_{|z|=3}\frac{1}{z^2-2i}\,dz$$

We note that the poles of the integrand are at $z= \pm(1+ i)$, both of which are contained in the circle $|z|=3$.

We can decompose the integrand as

$$\frac{1}{z^2-2i}=\frac{1}{2(1+i)}\left(\frac{1}{z-(1+i)} -\frac{1}{z+(1+i)}\right)$$

Then, we have

$$I=\frac{1}{2(1+i)}\left(\oint_{|z|=3}\frac{1}{z-(1+i)} \,dz-\oint_{|z|=3}\frac{1}{z+(1+i)}\right)=\frac{1}{2(1+i)}\left(2\pi i -2\pi i\right)=0$$

Comment: I wrote wrong, + is in middle but i thin solution is similar. thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  - Mark